# Rust: allocator API: expected struct `std::alloc::Global` when I provide my own allocator

Tags: rust

I want to use my own allocator in `alloc::vec::Vec::new_in`. However, Rust tells me "expected struct `std::alloc::Global`". How can I use my own allocator? I'm on Rust nightly 1.60.

```rust
#![feature(allocator_api)]

use std::alloc::{Allocator, AllocError, Layout};
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct PageAlignedAlloc;

unsafe impl Allocator for PageAlignedAlloc {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError> {
        std::alloc::System.allocate(layout.align_to(4096).unwrap())
    }

    unsafe fn deallocate(&self, ptr: NonNull<u8>, layout: Layout) {
        std::alloc::System.deallocate(ptr, layout)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = Vec::<u8>::new_in(PageAlignedAlloc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alloc::vec::Vec` uses the Global allocator as the default for the second generic parameter. You can see this in the source code of the alloc library:

```rust
pub struct Vec<T, #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global> {
    buf: RawVec<T, A>,
    len: usize,
}
```

This is the reason for the error message.

To compile your code, you need to provide a full type definition like this instead:

**Original answer** 
`let vec = Vec::<u8, PageAlignedAlloc>::new_in(PageAlignedAlloc);`

I don't know if there are any issues regarding that. I think the Rust compiler should be capable of inferring the type by itself in that case in the future.

---

**Updated, thanks to @eggyal 's comment**
`let vec = Vec::<u8, _>::new_in(PageAlignedAlloc);`

Comment: Rust *can* infer the allocator type parameter from the function argument.  However, because an explicit parameter list (`<u8>`) was provided, omitted optional parameters are deemed to be their default.  You could instead use an explicit wildcard here: `<u8, _>`.